# Font rendering (smoothing) not good on Mac OSX

Tags: windows, macos, fonts, rendering, smoothing

I wonder why fonts are rendered much better on Windows than on Mac OS X, below are two screenshots that show the difference in rendering the same piece of code in Intellij IDEA. The first screenshot is taken from Intellij IDEA on Windows 8.1 Pro and the second screenshot shows the same piece of code in Intellij IDEA on Mac OS X Yosemite.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I think the first screenshot (Windows) looks much better than the second one (Yosemite), I used the same font (Consolas).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, windows' font render looks much better. MS and Apple have different philosophies on font render. Apple thinks that it's best to render fonts to preserve the design of the typeface. MS believes that it must match pixel boundaries to prevent blur.

Comment: Yes, I've read about that. After using Yosemite for about 2 weeks now I don't think the fonts look too bad the same when I posted the question, it seems that my eyes got used to them.

Comment: The optimal solution is to get a Mac with retina display I think